# Trying to redefine \subsection

Tags: sectioning

I'd like to redefine \subsection. The reason is twofold: 1) it appears to be preceded by a built-in \parskip and this is too much of a lost space for me; 2) I'd like to have the line continued with additional text. I tried this:

```
 \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
```

and this works, except when I use \subsection* to prevent numbering.

Another question: is there a place online where I can find how \subsection is defined, in the first place.

Thank you

Comment: you do not need to redefine `\subsection` the spacing and font and whether the following text starts a new paragraph or follows the heading may all be specified in the section parameters either directly or using a package such as `secsty`

Comment: `\subsection` will be defined in the document class that you are using (but you have not said which) `article.cls` for example.

Answer (score 5):

IMO our approach is somehow  biased.

> 1) it appears to be preceded by a built-in \parskip and this is too
>   much of a lost space for me;

There is no parskip, it's another length (see below)

> 2) I'd like to have the line continued with additional text.

This is the usual behavior of `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`

In standard LaTeX, `\section` and all lower level sectioning commands are defined in  terms of the internal LaTeX generic command `\@startsection` as you can see wit the command `\meaning\section` in the body text.

In `book` class (10pt), you will get something like :

```
 \long macro:->\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@ }{-3.5ex \@plus
-1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }
```

What you need is :

1. reduce the first skip (4th argument) to something like 
   `{-1.5ex \@plus-0.7ex \@minus -.2ex}` (keep the glue and signs)
2. change the sign of the second skip (5th argument) with something like `{-2ex \@plus -.1ex}`

It can be done with `\renewcommand`, with `titlesec` packagge or with  `etoolbox`'s  `patchcmd`:

```
\patchcmd{\section}{{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}}{{-1.5ex \@plus-0.7ex \@minus -.2ex}}{\typeout{smaller skip OK}}{\typeout{smaller skip  failed}}%
\patchcmd{\section}{{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}}{{-2ex \@plus -.1ex}}{\typeout{same line OK}}{\typeout{same line failed}}%
```

**EDIT : patching `\subsection`**
The `\patchcmd` replaces ith 2nd argument by the 3rd one. Clearly the skip defined in standard class for `\subsection` is smaller than for `\section`. Therefore the second argument of `\patchcmd` must be read in the `\meaning\subsection` output.

An example of patching `\subsection` is (again for book, 10pt) :

```
\patchcmd{\subsection}{{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus - .2ex}}{{-1.5ex \@plus-0.7ex \@minus -.2ex}}{\typeout{spacing subsec OK}}{\typeout{spacing subsec failed}}%
\patchcmd{\subsection}{{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}}{{-2ex \@plus -.1ex}}{\typeout{same line subsec f}}{\typeout{same line subsec failed}}%
```

resulting in (both patched `\section` and `\subsection`) :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, jhor. My concern was more with \subsection than section. I tried following blindly in your footsteps:                        <pre>\patchcmd{\subsection}{{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}}{{-2ex \@plus -.1ex}}{\typeout{same line ss OK}}{\typeout{same line ss failed}}% </pre>                     But it did not work

Comment: I have edited my post to provide the patching of ``\subsection``. Of course: 
- the patching of ``\section`` and ``\subsection`` are independent
- it is up to you to choose the value of the 3rd argument (keeping it negative for run-in title, but unneeded glue)
- if you use another class, you will have to look at the definition of ``\subsection`` to ensiure that it is still defined on the basis of ``\@startsection`` and verify the values of the initial skip (2nd argument).